# Adding a total row into a table

Tags: php

I created a table that gets the absent days of employees, now i'm trying to add a row as a total that calculates the total of each column.. But i'm not sure how to do it. Any help please?

```
echo '  <div>

        <table>
            <tr> 
                <th>Month</th><th>Vacations</th>
            </tr>';

            for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
                echo '<tr>

                    <td>'.getCount($id,$year,$i,'Vacation').'</td>


                </tr>
                ';
            }

echo       '</table>
        </div>';
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. If you already have all the values and all you are looking for is how to add a total row, then why don't you just add the values and output the result? What is the question here?

Comment: @arkascha that's the question (add the values and output the result of every column) but i'm not sure how to do it\

Comment: I am sure you know how to add values. Currently you directly output the values you compute. Instead you could save the into an array first and output those saved values. As a result you then have the array holding all values available at the end of your loop iterating over all the month. All that is left to do is sum up the values in the array and output the result. I am sure you will manage yourself if you give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before loop

```
 $WeeklyVacationCount = 0;
 //.........other td
```

loop

```
 for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
    $WeeklyVacation = getCount($afnbr,$year,$i,'WeeklyVacation');
     $WeeklyVacationCount+=$WeeklyVacation;
    echo "<td>{$WeeklyVacation}</td>"; 
    //.........other td
```

after loop

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$WeeklyVacationCount}</td>";
echo "</tr>";
//.........other td
```

Comment: thank you, i'll accept the answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: everything is echoing and being displayed in the page

Comment: use "{$abc}"    not '{$abc}'

Comment: can we open a chat conv for a second pleasE?

Comment: use echo "<td>{$WeeklyVacation}</td>"  not   echo '<td>{$WeeklyVacation}</td>'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84250/discussion-between-dan-and-joe-lee).